# Method to add new or update existing item in C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, containskey

In some legacy code I have seen the following extension method to facilitate adding a new key-value item or updating an existing value:

Method-1 (legacy code):

```
public static void CreateNewOrUpdateExisting<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> map, TKey key, TValue value)
{            
    if (map.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        map[key] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        map.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Though, I have checked that `map[key] = value` does exactly the same job. That is, Method-1 could be replace with Method-2 below.

Method-2:

```
public static void CreateNewOrUpdateExisting<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> map, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    map[key] = value;
}
```

Now, my question is...
Could there be any problem if I replace Method-1 by Method-2?
Will it break in any possible scenario?

Also, I think this used to be the difference between HashTable and Dictionary. HashTable allows updating an item, or adding a new item by using indexer while Dictionary does not!
Has this difference been eliminated in C# > 3.0 versions?

The objective of this method is too not throw an exception if the user sends the same key-value again. The method should, if the key is:

- **found — update** the key's value, and
- **not found — create a new** key-value.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

> Could there be any problem if i replace Method-1 by Method-2?

No, just use `map[key] = value`. The two options are equivalent.

Regarding `Dictionary<>` vs. `Hashtable`: When you start Reflector, you see that the indexer setters of both classes call `this.Insert(key, value, add: false);` and the `add` parameter is responsible for throwing an exception, when inserting a duplicate key. So the behavior is the same for both classes.

Comment: This answer is fine for 99% of scenarios but if you are looking for thread-safe (as Parallel.For) check Filipe answer's https://stackoverflow.com/a/20020303/888472

Answer (score 65):

There's no problem. I would even remove the `CreateNewOrUpdateExisting` from the source and use `map[key] = value` directly in your code, because this this idiomatic C#; C# developers would typically know that `map[key] = value` means add or update.

Answer (score 30):

Old question but I feel I should add the following, even more because .NET 4.0 had already launched at the time the question was written.

Starting with .NET 4.0 there is the namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent` which includes collections that are thread-safe.

The collection `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<>` does exactly what you want. It has the `AddOrUpdate()` method with the added advantage of being thread-safe.

If you're in a high-performance scenario and not handling multiple threads the already given answers of `map[key] = value` are faster.

In most scenarios this performance benefit is insignificant. If so I'd advise to use the ConcurrentDictionary because:

1. It is in the framework - It is more tested and you are not the one who has to maintain the code
2. It is scalable: if you switch to multithreading your code is already prepared for it

Comment: this is perfect for the scenario using Parallel.For

Answer (score 13):

The only problem could be if one day

```
map[key] = value
```

will transform to -

```
map[key]++;
```

and that will cause a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 10):

Functionally, they are equivalent.

Performance-wise `map[key] = value` would be quicker, as you are only making single lookup instead of two.

Style-wise, the shorter the better :)

The code will in most cases seem to work fine in multi-threaded context. It however is **not** thread-safe without extra synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is not `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class, however you can avoid `KeyNotFoundException` while incrementing a value like:

```
dictionary[key]++; // throws `KeyNotFoundException` if there is no such key
```

by using [ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>  and its really nice method AddOrUpdate().](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#overloads).

Let me show an example:

```
var str = "Hellooo!!!";
var characters = new ConcurrentDictionary<char, int>();
foreach (var ch in str)
    characters.AddOrUpdate(ch, 1, (k, v) => v + 1);
```

Comment: Yes, seems very nice... but `ConcurrentDictionary` adds a lot of synchronization overhead for multithreading (i.e. locks). So there's a significant performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

Method 2 is better:

- Less code
- Does the exact same (except for some edge cases where it is not possible)
- Faster

Here is a benchmark sample to demonstrate the performance advantage of method 2.

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<DictionaryBenchmarks>();
    }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class DictionaryBenchmarks
{
    private readonly IDictionary<int, bool> _map = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
    private readonly int[] _arr = new int[20]
    {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
    };

    [Benchmark]
    public void CreateNewOrUpdateExistingWithContainsKeyCheck()
    {
        foreach (int item in _arr)
        {
            if (_map.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                _map[item] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _map.Add(item, true);
            }
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void CreateNewOrUpdateExistingWithoutContainsKeyCheck()
    {
        foreach (int item in _arr)
        {
            _map[item] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CreateNewOrUpdateExistingWithContainsKeyCheck | 232.0 ns | 4.19 ns | 10.52 ns | - |
| CreateNewOrUpdateExistingWithoutContainsKeyCheck | 131.9 ns | 2.12 ns | 4.83 ns | - |