# C# constructors as method's arguments?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# scripting.

I'm reading some code , and inside a class method there is a call to a function to add to a Dictionary instance named Listeners like this:

```
public class ......
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<Component>> Listeners = 
        new Dictionary<string, List<Component>>();

    public void AddListener(Component Listener, string NotificationName)
    {
        // Add listener to dictionary
        if (!Listeners.ContainsKey(NotificationName))
            Listeners.Add (NotificationName, new List<Component>());

        // Add object to listener list for this notification
        Listeners[NotificationName].Add(Listener);
    }
}
```

Now, it seems the call to Listeners.Add has a constructor call

```
new List<Component>()
```

as an argument.

Am I getting it right ?

Comment: Couple things that will make your life easier. First, there is a comma missing on the method declaration, right?  Second, name your local variables, formal parameters and local variables using the `camelCaseConvention`, not the `PascalCaseConvention`. It reads very strangely to experienced C# programmers to see a formal named `NotificationName`. It should be `notificationName`.  The compiler does not care, but the reader of your code will have the wrong intuitions about your code if you don't follow standard naming conventions.

Comment: You never have a *call* as an argument. You either have the return value of the call or a function pointer.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I am confused by your comment. Plainly the *argument* is a call -- or rather, an object creation; the value of the *formal parameter* corresponding to the argument will be the value produced by *evaluating the object creation*. It seems bizarre to say "the argument isn't a call, it is the result of evaluating a call". Would you say the same thing about, say, an integer literal? The argument to `abc(123)` is not an integer literal, it is the value produced by evaluating the integer literal?  This is a hairsplitting distinction; the value of all expressions is their evaluation!

Comment: @EricLippert: You can pass objects as arguments. And a call is a MSIL `call` instruction. You can't pass that as an argument. An integer is an object, so it can be passed as argument.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Nowhere in the C# specification does it say that a call is a `call` instruction. It says that a call is an *expression* whose *value* is the result of the call, and it says that *arguments* are *expressions*, and it says that arguments *correspond to formal parameters*, and it says that the values of the expressions will be copied to the formal parameters. Arguments are expressions. Calls are expressions. Therefore an argument can be a call. This seems very straightforward to me.

Comment: duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245064/method-to-add-new-or-update-existing-item-in-dictionary

Comment: @kain64b: This is not a duplicate of that question. That question is specifically about dictionary code. This question is about the general pattern of using a complex expression as an argument; that it happens to be about dictionaries is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now , it seems the call to `Listeners.Add` ...

You mean **not** the call to `Listeners[NotificationName].Add` I assume.

> ... has a constructor call `new List<Component>()` as an argument. Am I getting it right ?

Yes, the call has two *arguments*. The first argument is a formal parameter of the current method, and the second argument is an object creation expression.  The *values* of those arguments at runtime will be a *reference to a string* and a *reference to a newly created object*.

The order of operations here is, first the *receiver* is evaluated, then those argument values will be generated, and then the `Add` method will be invoked with those values copied into its *formal parameters* and the receiver value used as `this`.

The *meaning* of the code is "I have a map from names to lists of stuff; if this map has no mapping for a particular name, create a mapping from the name to an empty list of stuff". The second `Add` call then adds a single element to that list of stuff.

From a comment on another answer:

> I cannot get my hands on the instance reference outside that function call

Well, you *do* get your hands on it, on the very next line, by reading it right back out of the map again. But without a device that allows you to obtain that value by evaluating another expression, as you do here, you are correct. That expression simply produces a value; it does not associate any name with it that you can then use later on. If you'd wanted to do that then you'd want to create a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the call gets a new instance of a `List<Component>` as argument.

Unlike methods, constructors cannot be really referenced. While you can store a method reference in a delegate and later call it, you cannot do the same with constructors. Although that is more or less moot here, because

```
Listeners.Add (NotificationName, new List<Component>());
```

means roughly the following:

```
var param1 = NotificationName;
var param2 = new List<Component>();
Listeners.Add(param1, param2);
```

As you can see, a new list is created, and that new list is passed to the `Add` method.

Comment: Well, new List<Component>() is a constructor call right ? Then this call generates an instance which is passed as the function argument. But in the first case I cannot get my hands on the instance reference outside that function call.