# Method to get a value out of a Dictionary, or create one if it does not exist

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary>. Is there any function which gets the list at a particular key, and or creates a list if it does not exist. For example, this does not work:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
d["Bob"].Add("Fred");
```

Right now I'd have to do this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> l = d["Bob"];
if(l == null) { l = d["Bob"] = new List<string>(); }
l.Add("Fred");
```

I've considered adding an extension method Get(T key), which would allow me to do this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
d.Get("Bob").Add("Fred");
```

But I wanted to check to see if something like this doesn't already exist.

Looks like this is a dupe, that had a good answer:

[.NET Dictionary: get or create new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192906/net-dictionary-get-or-create-new)

Comment: That would throw an exception if the "Bob" key is not present.  Instead you'd want to use `TryGetValue`.

Comment: @neverendingqs No, the OP wants to also add something when missing, not just return the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method like:

```
public static void CreateNewOrUpdateExisting<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> map, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    map[key] = value;
}
```

Source:
[Method to Add new or update existing item in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245064/method-to-add-new-or-update-existing-item-in-dictionary)

Comment: The OP isn't trying to do an update or insert, which you've show is already built in, but a get or insert.